# Not able to see the progression of a file with `tail -f`

Tags: ubuntu, tail

It's a surprise why now `tail -f` isn't working while earlier was.

I've the below command to run for backup.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo tar -cvf /media/ubuntu/My*Linux/ub*data/zebra.tar /media/ubuntu/home > z1 2> z2 && echo "pass" || echo "fail"
```

To see the output and error, there are those 2 files `z1` and `z2`.

Now I want to see the output of the command on a terminal from file z1:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ tail -f z1
```

but this command is not showing the data that's getting appended with time.

I'm working on live install of Ubuntu 14.04.1 using usb pen drive. Can this be the reason?

Comment: Possibly unrelated to your problem, but you say `2 > z2`. I think the `stderr` redirection syntax `2>` does actually not allow a space bewtween the `2` and the `>`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz sorry that's my mistake. I've corrected

Comment: Since you gave tar an `f outputfilename` option, z1 is going to be an empty file.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick no z1 has the output corresponding to -v option. If I run 'cat z1', it will show all files backed up. The issue is the tail command isn't working.

Comment: @Ravi sorry, you are correct, GNU tar will write the list to stdout when v and f are used together. This goes against the written standard for tar. Will try to reproduce your problem. What directory are z1 and z2 in? The live CD's RAM disk or the USB drive? If USB, What is the filesystem type (ext3, vfat)?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick they're in /home/ubuntu (the one where you enter when you log in on live O.S.). It's USB drive with ext4 filesystem. Plz try to reproduce on live OS. You can check the tail command works on hard drive installation.

Comment: OK, I reproduced it. Cause and workaround in my answer (too much to put in a comment).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can reproduce this. It's a bug.

On an Ubuntu live CD, the filesystem that contains the default user's home directory is type [overlayfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109413/how-do-i-use-overlayfs), which claims to support [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) but doesn't.

So `tail -f` on a file on overlayfs tries to use `inotify` and then doesn't get any notifications when the file has changed.

The Ubuntu bug report for this is [Bug #882147: overlayfs does not implement inotify interfaces correctly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/882147). A workaround cited in that bug report, from Jim Meyering via Andrea Ranieri, is to use

```
tail -f ---disable-inotify file
```

(There really are three hyphens there.)